# how to execute the stored procedure in hibernate 3

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am new in hibernate. I am using hibernate 3 in my application using hibernate annotations , I am developing application in struts 1.3.

My question is :
I have googled a lot but could not understand how to call a stored procedure in **hibernate using annotations** , I have a simple scenario : suppose I have 2 fields in my jsp say 1) code 2) name , I have created a stored procedure in database for inserting those records into table. Now my problem is that how to execute it

```
 List<MyBean> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                          .getNamedQuery("mySp")
                        .setParameter("code", code)
                        .setParameter("name", name)
```

I don't know the exact code how to do this. But I guess something like that actually I come from jdbc background therefore have no idea how to do this and same thing I want when **selecting** the data from database using stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate provides many simple ways to call a SP like

1. Native SQL
2. Named Query in native SQL as Annotation/XML mapping file

Following link shows how each of above can be implemented

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query

Sample to run native SQL query using hibernate:

```
 Session session = getSession();
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableName WHERE external_id = :external_id");
    sqlQuery.setParameter("external_id", idValue);
    int count = ((BigInteger) sqlQuery.uniqueResult()).intValue();
    releaseSession(session);
```

Comment: You can find those link googleing for few keywords. Better if you can provide some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your stored procedure using Hibernate's SQLQuery with the same SQL as when you call it against the database. For example, in postgreSQL:

```
String query = "select schema.procedure_name(:param1)";
SQLQuery sqlquery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query);
sqlquery.setInteger("param1", "this is first parameter");
sqlQuery.list();
```

Hope it helps.